# Datagridview cell loses input value when focus is lost

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, cells

I have a `datagridview` which I have binded with a list. So the columns are generated dynamically. Here is the code for it

```
var result = (from gd in db.grades
              join std in db.students
              on gd.studentID equals std.studentID
              where gd.courseID == courseID
              select new
              {
                 Name = std.studentName,
                 Registration = std.studentID,
                 QA = gd.QA,
                 S1 = gd.S1,
                 S2 = gd.S2,
                 Final = gd.Final                                  
              }).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = result;
```

Now the cells are `ReadOnly == true` by default which is what good, but when a user selects a cell it should be editable, so what I'm doing is in the `CellDoubleClickEvent` I'm setting the mode for that particular cell to `Readonly = true`. Following is the code for `CellDoubleClickEvent`

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{            
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = false;
}
```

which works, makes the cell editable, but after the cell is edited and I click somewhere else(loose focus) the input(edited) value is lost.

**I want to retain the input(edited values in cell) so that I could utilize it later like save it etc etc**

Answer (score 0):

You should raise event of DataGridViewRowStateChanged, to alert the DataGridView a row has been changed. Then you should provide handler for this to ensure your changed data is propagated back to the DataGridViewRow gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem and i used a work around for that.
I bind my comboboxcell with SelectedIndexChange event
eg. `cbo.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ComBox_SelectedIndexChanged);`

and in that method I took the new value, removed it from the datasource and putted back at first position by using List<> method Insert(pos,value) then in cell formatting event i set the value of that cell to the first value of datasource like:

```
if ((e.ColumnIndex == 4) && ((DataGridViewCell)dataGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]).GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxCell))  //check for ur comboboxcell index
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGrid[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            if (cell.DataSource != null)
            {
                List<string> values = (List<string>)cell.DataSource;
                if (values.Count > 0)
                {
                    e.Value = values[0];
                    e.FormattingApplied = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

hope it works for u.